# Cell in tableview don't show all the text of label in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a TableView in a ScrollView. I set some constraint and auto layout to dynamic cell and dynamic height of table view. But i get some problems with each cell, some of each cell don't show all of content. Any body help?

[image: My information label]

And auto layout of number in right of information label

[image: Autolayout of number label]

Code of table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Code for dynamic tableview

```
    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }
```

My problem now:
[image: Result of code]

I'm stuck fews day. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you can do here.

- Try setting text label's bottom constraint to "Greater than or Equal".
- Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` after setting tableView height constraint

Comment: The problem of content in label is solved, but it leads to another problem. I return 13 cell but it only display 10 cell, or less cell than expected. But with small cell, it will return a long space of white background without dynamic height. Do you know about this

Comment: Less cell count could be because last few cells are squeezing. Confirm this by using "Debug View Hierarchy". Also, check if contentSize provided by tableView is correct (estimated) according to your cell size.

Comment: what do you think about case of small number of cell

Answer (score 0):

add this 2 lines in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

check this example as well for constraints

https://github.com/iDhaval/TableCellDynamicHeight

Comment: This is not work. I already add this

Comment: have you checked the github example?

Comment: I follow the example and the comment of Muhammad Raza. But another problem now is when the number of cell is too small, it will show the space of white without dynamic height. Or number of cell is too much, it will missing some cell in the end

Comment: into your code you added numberOfRowsInSection : 10 thats why it is showing only 10 
add 13 there instead

Comment: yes, i know numberOfRowsInSection, but problem is using 13 numberOfRowsInSection, only display 10. a little bug here

Answer (score 0):

UILabel has an attribtute called "numberOfLines" and as default it is set to 1, which gives one line in a cell. We can set as many lines as We want but setting this value to 0 will allow us to adapt the number of lines in our cell to the number of lines we actually need. So add a line of code: `cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0` to the func. All should looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
           cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
           return cell
 }
```